# qmobilityglobal.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qt-mobility

I'm trying to compile one of QtMobility's samples - [hapticsplayer](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qtmobility/hapticsplayer.html), but I can't even compile it, because the compiler can't find Qt Mobility's headers.

Since this is one of the samples shipped with Qt SDK, I assume that everything about the project configuration/sources/etc. is correct. So I must be **missing Qt Mobility** in my Qt installation, or something like that.

Here's a screenshot of Maintain Qt SDK's package manager:

[image]

Here I'm pasting the compiler errors:

```
In file included from ..\hapticsplayer\hapticsplayer.cpp:41:
..\hapticsplayer\/hapticsplayer.h:41:29: error: qmobilityglobal.h: No such file or directory
..\hapticsplayer\/hapticsplayer.h:45:31: error: qfeedbackactuator.h: No such file or directory
..\hapticsplayer\/hapticsplayer.h:46:29: error: qfeedbackeffect.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ..\hapticsplayer\hapticsplayer.cpp:41:
..\hapticsplayer\/hapticsplayer.h:53: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'class'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - it was because of the build target I had selected.

I had been building for Symbian Anna, but when I switched to building for Symbian S60 (which is the target I actually wanted to build for anyway), the project compiled successfully. Symbian Anna had been selected by default when creating the new project, that's why I was building for it instead of for S60.